# Material-UI Autocomplete popup menu won't stay open

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

With Reactjs I'm using Material UI (core v4.12.3, lab 4.0.0-alpha.60) autocomplete which has been set up as a multiselectible drop down and I'm having trouble keeping the menu open. Whenever an option is selected the popup menu closes and I have to manually open it again just to select another option.

I have already set disableCloseOnSelect={true}
But it still doesn't work

Looking around i think the issue might be linked to the fact I use onChange to save the selected values to state. Is there any workaround to getting disableCloseOnSelect to work? I think one way might be to handle open/closing the menu manually via saving to state but since I have several of these drop downs it doesn't seem good to manage the state for all of them

Comment: Please read this [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 7):

```
<Autocomplete
  disableCloseOnSelect
/>
```

This is the property you need ;)

Comment: The OP already says that that prop doesn't work. And in fact it doesn't. It must be a bug in Material-UI.

Comment: It seems to work for me with mui@5.10.4